Extracting the slice arguments in variables
Lets assume we have the Python line:
print(languages[1::2])

Is there any generic way to extract the values of start, stop and step in other variables?
I want to see a start variable with value 1,  a stop variable with None and a step variable with value 2
or a tuple of these three elements
I am new in Python and I wondering if I can create a program which will simulate the slice functionality for strings, lists and tuples just as an coding exercise.
So I need to extract the values of a previously executed print command and use them.

I'm not sure how the "previously executed" part of your requirements follows from the rest. In pretty much any sane answer (including the one already present) you need to put a datatype into place that records the parameters used before the slice operation.

It would be more helpful if you tell us exactly what you are trying to do, i.e. elaborate on what this means exactly: "create a program which will simulate the slice functionality for strings, lists and tuples just as an coding exercise." because "extract the values of a previously executed print command and use them" doesn't really make much sense.

In the example you can't get the values after-the-fact, but you could subclass list to capture the last index or slice used via the __getitem__ method, which receives the inner [] value:
class MemoList(list):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.last_arg = None

    def __getitem__(self, arg):
        self.last_arg = arg
        return super().__getitem__(arg)

languages = MemoList(['English', 'Spanish', 'French', 'Chinese'])
print(languages[1::2])
print(languages.last_arg)  # slice in this case
print(languages.last_arg.start, languages.last_arg.stop, languages.last_arg.step)
print(languages[3])
print(languages.last_arg)  # integer in this case

Output:
['Spanish', 'Chinese']
slice(1, None, 2)
1 None 2
Chinese
3

